# Generalizing the Rational Roots Theorem to complex rational roots

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, factoring, rational-numbers

Is there a generalization of the Rational Roots Theorem to complex rational roots? [This answer on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/180725/48976) shows that it can be applied to purely imaginary rational roots. I'm curious about roots of the form $\frac{m}{n}+\frac{p}{q}i$ however, where $m, p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n, q \in \mathbb{N^+}$.

---

#### Some Observations

Let's assume for simplicity that the polynomial $P(x)$ has only real-valued coefficients. Then if $\frac{m}{n}+\frac{p}{q}i$ is a root, so is $\frac{m}{n}-\frac{p}{q}i$ by the Complex Conjugate Root Theorem. This means that $P(x)$ is divisible by $x^2-\frac{2m}{n}x+(\frac{m^2}{n^2}+\frac{p^2}{q^2})$. Or in other words, $P(x)$ contains a quadratic factor with only rational coefficients, and where the leading term and constant term have the same sign.

Another observation is that we can rewrite $P(\frac{m}{n}+\frac{p}{q}i)$ as the sum of a real and imaginary polynomial over 4 variables, and we can set both of these polynomials equal to $0$. This approach gets out of hand really quickly however.

Any ideas on how to approach this? Does a generalized theorem simply not exist?

Comment: Yes, this can be generalized as follows : if $R$ is a unique factorization domain and $f(x)=a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x+a_0$ has a root $p/q$ in the fraction field of $R$, with $\mathrm{gcd}(p,q)=1$ then $p$ divides $a_0$ and $q$ divides $a_n$ (see _Field and Galois Theory_ (Patrick Morandi), p. 235).

Comment: The high-school proof of RRT works over any GCD domain, i.e. any domain where gcds exist (which includes UFDs such as the Gaussian integers)

Comment: Can either of these observations be expanded into an answer?